# How to deal with 'internal:' in your link->uri?

Tags: 8, navigation

I have a link field, which I can populate with both internal and external links:

> /node/123

I'm building an API that parses the node and returns the URL from the link field:

`$node->my_field->uri`

Which returns `internal:/node/123` which makes this URL useless.

If I try using `use Drupal\Core\Url;` and `Url::fromUri($node->my_field->uri)`, I get a 500 error!

So what is the correct approach for getting a formatted URL, that can parse both internal and external links?

Answer (score 2):

just kidding. To help future devs with this issue, check the logs *duh and you'll see this:

> PHP message: Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "The URI '' is invalid.

So, check for the uri value first!

`$node->my_field->uri ? Url::fromUri($node->my_field->uri)->toString() : null,`

Comment: You can also use $node->get('my_field')->get(0)->getUrl(). you still need to check it for not being empty though